# longest common subsequence of three integer sequences

Tags: python, dynamic-programming

I've seen similar answers to this but not specific to the type of approach I'm using. I'm trying to find the longest common subsequence of the three sequences of integers. In this case a = [8, 3, 2, 1, 7] b = [8, 2, 1, 3, 8, 10, 7] c = [6, 8, 3, 1, 4, 7] and the output should be 3 where the longest common subsequence is either [8, 3, 7] or [8, 1, 7]. My code outputs the integers that the sequences have in common but not the "sequence" they have in common, the length of that sequence and the "edit distance" for the three sequences, which is the same as the length as the common integers. I have used a modification of an edit distance algorithm and modified it to cope with a third sequence. I need to modify this to produce the common sequence and not just the common integers. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
def lcs3(a, b, c):


        n = len(a)
        m = len(b)
        l = len(c)

        E = [[[0 for k in range(l+1)] for j in range(m+1)] for i in range(n+1)]

        common = []

        for i in range(1,n+1):
            E[i][0][0] = i

        for j in range(1,m+1):
            E[0][j][0] = j

        for k in range(1,l+1):
            E[0][0][k] = k    


        for j in range(1,m+1):
            for i in range(1,n+1):
                for k in range(1,l+1):
                    #insertion between first and 2nd sequence
                    insertionij = E[i][j-1][k] + 1

                    #insertion between 2nd and 3rd sequence
                    insertionjk = E[i][j][k-1] + 1

                    #deletion between 1st and 2nd sequence
                    deletionij = E[i-1][j][k] + 1

                    #deletion between 2nd and 3rd sequence
                    deletionjk = E[i][j-1][k] + 1

                    #matches and mismatches between 1st through to 3rd sequences
                    matchijk = E[i-1][j-1][j-1]
                    mismatchijk = E[i-1][j-1][k-1] + 1

                    if a[i-1] == b[j-1] == c[k-1]:
                        E[i][j][k] = min(insertionij, insertionjk, deletionij, deletionjk, matchijk)

                        common.append(a[i-1])

                    else:
                        E[i][j][k] = min(insertionij, insertionjk, deletionij, deletionjk, mismatchijk)

        common = list(set(common))
        #print(E)
        return (E[n][m][l], len(common), common)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very similar to how we solve lcs question on two arrays.

```
def lcs3(a, b, c):
    n = len(a)
    m = len(b)
    l = len(c)

    if 0 in (n, m, l):
        return 0

    E = [[[0] * (l + 1) for _ in range(m + 1)] for _ in range(n + 1)]

    for i in reversed(range(n + 1)):
        for j in reversed(range(m + 1)):
            for k in reversed(range(l + 1)):
                if i == n or j == m or k ==l:
                    E[i][j][k] = 0
                elif a[i] == b[j] == c[k]:
                    E[i][j][k] = 1 + E[i + 1][j + 1][k + 1]
                else:
                    E[i][j][k] = max(E[i + 1][j][k], E[i][j + 1][k], E[i][j][k + 1])

    return E[0][0][0]
```

Comment: Omit my answer. I didn't realize common string also need to be returned.

Comment: No, the only required output was the length of the subsequence. I thank you greatly for your answer!